# IE 10 + jQuery - Not able to use "append" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, internet-explorer-10

I am running an HTML 5 application using the KendoUI framework. Once of the screens deal with XML data that needs to be parsed and processed.

This screen needs to be shown as a popup and that data is shown in a grid inside this popup. To do this, I am calling a function on clicking the "show-popup" button inside which I have the following piece of code :

```
    var tTranslationXML = XMLFromString(_SelectedCategoryValueRecord.DisplayTextTranslation);
.
.
.
// other stuff but nothing that changes "tTranslationXML"
. 
.
if (_SelectedCategoryValueRecord.DisplayTextTranslation) // and there are values in the translation field
            {
                var $language = $(tTranslationXML).find('Language');
                var $oldTranslation = $($language).find("en-US");
                if ($oldTranslation.length == 0)
                    $oldTranslation = $($language).find(GetCorrectedCase("en-US"));
                if ($oldTranslation.length == 0) {
                    var $newTranslation = $.createElementNS("en-US").text(_UpdatedDisplayText);
                    $language.append($newTranslation);
                }
            }
```

And if you are wondering what "XMLFromString" is, its nothing but a simple helper to parse the XML data from a string variable

```
function XMLFromString(pXMLString) 
{
if (!pXMLString)
    pXMLString = "<Language></Language>";
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var oXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    oXML.loadXML(pXMLString);
    return oXML;
} else {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(pXMLString, "text/xml");
}
}
```

My issue is that this works fine on Chrome and Firefox but I get an error in IE10 when this particular line executes -

**"$language.append($newTranslation);"**

I am basically trying to append a new translation value to the contents of my variable here.

The error is as follows : 
**SCRIPT13: Type mismatch 
jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2 character 71981**

[image: Please see the screenshot of the error in the IE10 developer tools console here]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I think I came across someone recently who faced a problem with the latest JQuery on IE10. The problem was fixed with an earlier version. Have you tried that?

Comment: Try something less complicated (through the console) to rule out any other errors; `$('body').append($('<div>Hello World</div>'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.

I figured out that the issue was to avoid using the method "createElementNS" and instead use the "createElement" method when creating the parent node. Subsequent appendages to this node do not throw up any issues. However there will issues when you append to a node that was originally created using "createElementNS".

This seems specific to IE10 because the NS method worked fine on chrome, FF and Safari.

Thank you all for the tips and ideas.